# Is parameter name able to become return type in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

```
Hi there！I meet the following code in IOS swift development class. 

class UpdateToAttributedStringsPolicy: NSEntityMigrationPolicy {

override func createDestinationInstances(forSource sInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws {
    // Call super
    try super.createDestinationInstances(forSource: sInstance, in: mapping, manager: manager)

    // Get the (updated) destination Note instance we're modifying
    guard let destination = manager.destinationInstances(forEntityMappingName: mapping.name, sourceInstances: [sInstance]).first else { return }

    // Use the (original) source Note instance, and instantiate a new
    // NSAttributedString using the original string
    if let text = sInstance.value(forKey: "text") as? String {
        destination.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: text), forKey: "attributedText")
    }
  }
}
```

In this line of code

```
override func createDestinationInstances(forSource sInstance: NSManagedObject, in mapping: NSEntityMapping, manager: NSMigrationManager) throws
```

the sInstance and manager is a parameter name in the function createDestinationInstances,but in

```
try super.createDestinationInstances(forSource: sInstance, in: mapping, manager: manager)
```

they become a return name,how this works?
 And why call super here?Does it mean super.init?

Thanks!

Comment: Parameter name is local variable for use later in same function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you are asking how you could use `sInstance` as the value even if it is just a label?

As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) (Function Declaration -> Parameter Names section), the `sInstance` is actually a parameter name, not label.

```
parameter_name: parameter_type
argument_label parameter_name: parameter_type
_ parameter_name: parameter_type
```

So while this is correct

```
try super.createDestinationInstances(forSource: sInstance, in: mapping, manager: manager)
```

This is wrong:

```
 try super.createDestinationInstances(forSource: forSource, in: in, manager: manager)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,Tien.
And why call super here?Does it mean super.init?

Comment: @Zetao, author is overriding the function `createDestinationInstances` of parent class. But she still need to call it, that's why there is `super.`